# Query string doesn't output the whole query

Tags: php, jquery, get

```
<?php
// GET contains 2 keywords, James+Bond,
$_GET['query'];
$query = $_GET['query'];

// This will return only James, Doesn't matter either if I referens the $_GET['query'] directly.
echo $query;
?>
```

What would make that query break? spaces?

Comment: Paste ur query string here or paste ur url here

Comment: `spaces?` seems to be all param key and values should not contain any spaces.

Comment: @Jai Url can contain spaces. But it must be encoded.

Comment: My bad, I had previously limited the query string to contain only A-Za-z characters within the htaccess file, by adding + to the list, issue got resolved.